# How to open eclipse memory anaylzer index files in eclipse

Tags: heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I've heap dump file testdump.hprof. I parsed this file using below command.

`./ParseHeapDump.sh /home/rajkumar/Documents/heap-dump-ads03/testdump.hprof`

The above command generated the below files.

> testdump.threads
>
> testdump.idx.index
>
> testdump.o2c.index
>
> testdump.a2s.index
>
> testdump.inbound.index
>
> testdump.outbound.index
>
> testdump.o2hprof.index
>
> testdump.index
>
> testdump.domIn.index
>
> testdump.o2ret.index
>
> testdump.domOut.index

I've installed eclipse memory analyzer plugin im my eclipse IDE. I don't know how to open the index files in IDE for analyzing. I opened the index file directly but it shows some binary string.

Any idea how can I open the index files in the eclipse?

Comment: Not sure why are you trying to open those index files. MAT created them while parsing a heap dump. If you want to analyze heap dump using ParseHeapDump.sh script then you need to pass the name of the report you want to generate. For example, if you want to see "Leak Suspect Report" then you can run it like following: ParseHeapDump.sh path/to/dump.hprof org.eclipse.mat.api:suspects                                                                            It will then create a .zip file with dump's name. Extract it and open index.html and you will be able to see the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have installed MAT into Eclipse, open the Memory Analysis perspective and then do File > Open Heap Dump > "/home/rajkumar/Documents/heap-dump-ads03/testdump.hprof" and that will open the heap dump using the existing index files (so no reparsing is needed).
Then go to the toolbar 'Run Expert System Test' > 'Leak Suspects' to run the leak suspects report.

As suv3ndu said, you can also run the report from the command line. You can also open an existing report zip from the GUI using 'Run Expert System Test' > 'Open Report'.